# Trying to make a login for my admin panel if matches password from database

Tags: php

I  have already put user name and password in database, now what I am trying to do is when admin puts that user name and password that I have stored in database, they can access next page otherwise error.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
     $user=$_REQUEST['user'];
     $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
     $q = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminlogin"));
     $r = mysql_query($q);
     if ( $user == "admin" && $password == "adminadmin" ) {
         echo "welcome";
         Header("Location: index.php");
     }
}
```

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$user=$_REQUEST['user'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

$q = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminlogin"));  
    $r = mysql_query($q); 
    if ( $user == "admin" && $password == "adminadmin" ) 
    {
  echo "welcome";
     Header("Location: index.php"); 
    }

Comment: I would recommend you to add a question to your post, so that there can be a answer

Comment: i am trying to use this query

Comment: There is a edit button (bottom left) of you post to edit your question and add some code + a real question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28362386/edit

Comment: i am not allowed to post more questions

Comment: I've tried tidying up your question, including adding the code from your comment, and removing four spaces between each word in your sentences  (!!). If you write questions like this, it is not a wonder that you've hit the question ban.

Comment: halfer thanku so much but the notice that i am getting is that you can post your next question after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
 $user=$_REQUEST['user'];
 $password=$_REQUEST['password'];

 //Execute query, adjust the name of the columns to the one you've used in your table
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE user = '$user' and password = '$password'");

 //Get the results from the query
 $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

 //If any rows, the login is okay
 if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
      //User okay, redirect him to the success page
      header("location: index.php");
}
```